Is Malcev completion an embedding?
The Malcev completion of an abstract group $G$ over a field $k$ of characteristic zero is defined by
$$\hat G = \mathbb{G}(\widehat{k[G]}) ,$$
the group-like part of the completed (by the augmentation ideal $I$) group ring.
Question: Suppose that $G$ is residually nilpotent and torsion-free. Then, is the natural map $G\to \hat G$ an injection?
I've heard that this is true for free groups, but without any proofs. If $G$ is further nilpotent, I could prove it using the fact that $G_n = (1+I^n)\cap G$ (for the notation and the proof, see this MO post and Theorem 12.1.6 of CDBooK by Chmutov-Duzhin-Mostovoy, respectively).
Any comments or references are appreciated.

This map is an embedding if and only if $G$ is residually torsion-free-nilpotent, which is much stronger that being both torsion free and residually nilpotent.

For a specific example, fix a prime $p$ and an integer $n\geq 3$ and let $G$ be the corresponding congruence subgroup $\ker(\text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z})\to \text{SL}_n(\mathbb{Z}/(p))$. Then $G$ is torsion free and, by conisdering deeper conruence subgroups, it is residually (finite-)nilpotent. However $G$ has no non-trivial torsion free nilpotent qoutient (e.g by proerty T), so $\hat{G}$ is trivial.

Thank y'all for the answer and a counterexample. Under the residual torsion-free-nilpotency, is it also true that the map $k[G]\to\widehat{k[G]}$ is also injective?

Sure, since the map $G\rightarrow \widehat{k[G]}$ is.

I'm sorry; I think that's not necessarily the case (at least in general). Even if $X\to V$ is an injection for a set $X$ and a vector space $V$, this may not induce an injective linear map. Are there other reason that I'm missing?

You're right of course, but group-like elements in a Hopf algebra are linearly independant so that's fine.

Wow, I didn't know that. Thank you so much!
